# Narrow Down Ranges of Numbers to a Single Number using python

Tags: python

I want to be able to narrow down a range of numbers , to smaller ranges of numbers, then to a single number by successive operations.

I want to be able to divide a range of numbers (say 1 to 110) into up to 10 groups of ranges, say (range 1 to 11.0, range 12.0 to 22.0, and so on).

The choice of range would depend on an input choice 1 to 10. The end result of many successive operations would be a single number out of the whole range. It can be a float.

For example: If I have a range of numbers 1 to 110, and want to divide them into 10 ranges and choose input 3, that would give the 3rd range, 23.0 to 33.0.

Then, using another input choice, divide those numbers again by 10 to make smaller ranges of numbers until I get to a single number (integer or float).

Additionally the program should be able to handle floats.
I don't want to do the whole operation in one calculation since the starting range could be high, eg: 100,000, and it could change, and I want to be able to choose the groups via input.
Plus, I assume the calculations would increase exponentially as the groups increase, making this program impractical to write in a short time.
I assume making some type of repeatable function would shorten the time it takes to write the program.
If you find it easier to use a smaller number of groups in your example  (say, two groups with two input choices) that's fine. I can change it to make more groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

change the `begin` , `end`, `num_groop` as you want:

```
begin = 1
end = 110
num_groop = 5
num_in_groop = (begin + end) // num_groop
lis = []


end = num_in_groop
for _ in range(num_groop):
    lis.append(list(range(begin, end+1)))
    begin += num_in_groop
    end += num_in_groop
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what he meant?

Comment: That's a nice way to do groups Aric a. Next I need to choose 1 of those groups using an input, divide that into groups, and repeat until we have just 1 number. Also, the program needs to handle floats.